# Passing options across multiple style files

Tags: packages, package-writing, package-options

I load a package, say aaa.sty, from a main document.

In aaa.sty, I also load a package, say bbb.sty.

The reason why I maintain two style files is that aaa.sty is in the TeX default folder, and bbb.sty is in my dropbox folder.

The problem arises when I try to pass options from a main document to bbb.sty.

I use the following way:

**Main document:**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[option={option_a=F, option_b=T}]{aaa}
\begin{document}
\xxx \yyy
\end{document}
```

**aaa.sty:**

```
\ProvidesPackage{aaa}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\DeclareOptionX{option}{\def\myoption{#1}}
\ProcessOptionsX\relax
\usepackage[\myoption]{"C:/Users/XXX/Dropbox/YYY/ZZZ/bbb"}
```

**bbb.sty:**

```
\ProvidesPackage{bbb}
\DeclareOptionX{option_a}{\def\xxx{#1}}
\DeclareOptionX{option_b}{\def\yyy{#1}}
\ProcessOptionsX\relax
```

This works well in my main computer (TeX live 2019 installed), but I found out that this does not work in my sub computer (TeX live 2020 installed).

Even in my sub computer, if I changed the following absolute path

```
\usepackage[\myoption]{"C:/Users/XXX/Dropbox/YYY/ZZZ/bbb"}
```

to the following relative path

```
\usepackage[\myoption]{bbb}
```

then, it works well.

Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of I found a solution by myself by chance.
I should use

```
\usepackage[\myoption]{C:/Users/XXX/Dropbox/YYY/ZZZ/bbb}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage[\myoption]{"C:/Users/XXX/Dropbox/YYY/ZZZ/bbb"}
```

Still don't know why, but it works then.